# Combine arrays and add flag to it if matches the ID

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have two arrays that are identical in structure.

```js
let TaskArray=[
  {"TaskID:"171","TaskName":"task1","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"},
  {"TaskID:"170","TaskName":"task2","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"},
  {"TaskID:"169","TaskName":"task3","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"},
  {"TaskID:"168","TaskName":"task4","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"},
  {"TaskID:"167","TaskName":"task5","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"},
  {"TaskID:"166","TaskName":"task6","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"},
  {"TaskID:"165","TaskName":"task7","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"},
  {"TaskID:"164","TaskName":"task8","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"},
  {"TaskID:"163","TaskName":"task9","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"},
  {"TaskID:"162","TaskName":"task10","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"}
]

let TaskDetailsArray = [
  {"TaskID:"171","TaskName":"task1","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"},
  {"TaskID:"170","TaskName":"task2","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"},
  {"TaskID:"169","TaskName":"task3","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"},
  {"TaskID:"168","TaskName":"task4","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"},
]
```

I need to compare the two arrays and set the flag isAssigned to true if an item from the second array is found by id in the first array, and false otherwise.

```js
matcheArray = [
  {"TaskID:"171","TaskName":"task1","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3",isAssigned: true},
  {"TaskID:"170","TaskName":"task2","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3",isAssigned: true},
  {"TaskID:"169","TaskName":"task3","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3",isAssigned: true},
  {"TaskID:"168","TaskName":"task4","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3",isAssigned: true},
  {"TaskID:"167","TaskName":"task5","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"},
  {"TaskID:"166","TaskName":"task6","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"},
  {"TaskID:"165","TaskName":"task7","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"},
  {"TaskID:"164","TaskName":"task8","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"},
  {"TaskID:"163","TaskName":"task9","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"},
  {"TaskID:"162","TaskName":"task10","TaskGroup":"group","UserID":"3"}
]
```

The code below works ok, but I'm not sure whether there is a better way to accomplish it. Please suggest.

```js
   for (var i = 0; i < TaskArray.length; i++) {
                        for (var k = 0; k < this.TaskDetailsArray.length; k++) {
                            if (TaskArray[i].TaskID == this.TaskDetailsArray[k].TaskID) {
                               
                                if (!this.TaskDetailsArray[k].isAssigned) {
                                    this.TaskDetailsArray[k].isAssigned = true;
                                };
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: A snippet is not just a better code-block. Only use a snippet if its content can be executed and with that adds something to the question (e.g. produces the error you're talking about).

Comment: Please fix the broken syntax (visible by the broken syntax highlighting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const comparedArray = taskArray.map(item => {
   return {
...item,
isAssigned: TaskDetailsArray.some(secondItem => secondItem.TaskId === item.TaskId );
  }
})
```